# WHMCS how to add function to the system's cron job?

Tags: php, cron, whmcs

I created an `addon` for `whmcs` in `whmcs/modules/addons` directory which I want to run it by the system's `cron` job. 
WHMCS's `cron` job uses this:

```
php -q /var/www/html/whmcs/whmcs/admin/cron.php
```

to automate module functions (suspension, termination) and billing settings.

Any ideas to add function to automate my addon using the same `cron` job while `cron.php` is encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are still looking at this in 2018, docs have changed, you can find DailyCronJob docs here:
https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/cron/#dailycronjob

Also here you can find an entry point for modules creation in WHMCS:
https://developers.whmcs.com/modules/

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DailyCronJob](http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:DailyCronJob) hook, add it to the hooks.php in your module.

Comment: This answer does not help at all.. The link literally gives no information on where to start or how to proceed.

Comment: hello @Marcel for someone who created an addon that should be enough answer. Unless you're the one who asked the question I see no reason for you to down vote my answer. please reconsider. Better than down voting, can you please contribute with the "Helpful answer"!!!

Comment: StackOverflow admins, can you please reconsider the down vote of @Marcel. I find it not helping in any way. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is too short - one line at the time of writing; try expanding it a little, and explaining how hooks.php works.  Does hooks.php in a module get called even if the module isn't loaded?  eg payment gateway.